# Pulling Pixels that changed between 2 images and saving to a new using image magick convert while keeping the original colors

Tags: linux, imagemagick

Im trying to get the difference between 2 images and saving it to a new for faster file transfers.

but when getting the difference using this command `compare -compose src /tmp/.send.png ~/.cache.png .difference.png` It works but everything that changed is red? How can i make it the original color or make it not change the color of the image?

Comment: Please show your input images. It is not clear what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what you want for the result. Here are two different ways in ImageMagick. There is a small blue square added to image 2.

The following is Unix syntax. Windows syntax is slightly different. If using ImageMagick 7, replace convert with magick.

Input 1:

[image]

Input 2:

[image]

```
convert lena.png lena_blue.png \
\( -clone 0,1 -compose difference -composite -colorspace gray \) \
-delete 1 \
\( -clone 0 -fill green1 -colorize 100 \) \
+swap -compose over -composite \
lena_diff.png
```

Highlight difference in green:

[image]

Black out the image except where difference:

```
convert lena.png lena_blue.png \
\( -clone 0,1 -compose difference -composite -colorspace gray -threshold 0 \) \
-delete 1 \
+swap -compose multiply -composite \
lena_diff2.png
```

[image]

Comment: Which one did you want?

Comment: Black out the image where difference

Comment: It is blacked out where there is no difference in my example. The original image shows in the small square where there are differences.